# How to display an expandable dynamic table using Angular 5?

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

**My Objective**: To display an expandable dynamic table without using any external table-library.

**What I did**: Currently, I'm looping inside a `<div>` to display a table (It works!). Now, I also want to add a button in front of every table-row, which when clicked will display some additional information related to that particular row. For that purpose I'm using [`ng-bootstrap's Collapse`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples).

**Issue I'm facing**: As every row is expandable and the number of row is dynamic, I'm unable to figure out how can I build an expandable table row without initializing some variable within `.ts` file first. Also, I want all the rows to be closed at the beginning. As of now, all the expansion button have same `id` and refer to same `boolean variable`. Hence, whenever I try to expand one row, every row gets expanded.

Here's my code in `HTML`:

```
<div style="display: table-row" *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="'isCollapsed'+row.id = !'isCollapsed'+row.id" [attr.aria-expanded]="false"
        aria-controls="'collapse'+row.id">
        E
    </button>
    <div id="'collapse'+row.id" [ngbCollapse]="'isCollapsed'+row.id">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                Some dynamic table content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk" [id]="row.id" [name]="row.id">
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> {{row.id}} </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> {{row.name}} </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> {{row.address}} </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> {{row.package}} </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> {{row.notes}} </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> {{row.price}} </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"> {{row.status}} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array with rowsControls that will store information about collapse. In your component, try something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-collapse-basic',
  templateUrl: './collapse-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdCollapseBasic implements OnInit {
  rowsControls = [];
  rows = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'First row'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Second row'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Third row'
  }]

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rows.forEach(row => {
      this.rowsControls.push({
        isCollapsed: true
      })
    });
  }
}
```

And then template bind to each row `isCollapse` property like following:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows; let index = index">
  <p>
    <button 
      type="button" 
      class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
      (click)="rowsControls[index].isCollapsed = !rowsControls[index].isCollapsed"
      [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse_' + row.id"
    >
      Toggle
    </button>
  </p>
  <div 
    id="collapse_{{ row.id }}" 
    [ngbCollapse]="rowsControls[index].isCollapsed"
  >
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        Some dynamic content of {{ row.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check the demo here: https://angular-dkxc1t.stackblitz.io

Comment: One more thing, is writing `"'collapse_' + row.id"` vs `"collapse_{{ row.id }}"` effectively same?

Comment: You can read more about interpolation and property binding here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1424/angular-interpolation-property-data-binding